# Kotlin instance variables in Android: assign random value vs dealing with nullability

Tags: android, kotlin

Imagine two (equivalent) scenarios in Anroid development with an instance variable:

```
private var myAmazingVariable: Int? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
myAmazingVariable = incomingIntent.getInt("INT_PLACEHOLDER", 0);
}
```

This scenario sets the initial value as `null`, meaning we have to deal with nullability.

```
private var myAmazingVariable = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
myAmazingVariable = incomingIntent.getInt("INT_PLACEHOLDER", 0);
}
```

In contrast to the above, this scenario initially sets the `variable` as 0, meaning we don't have to deal with nullability BUT probably require some initial resoureces at initiation.

My question is which of these is a better approach. Both `lateinit` or not defining a variable are unfortunately not options.

Comment: Your premise that a nullable variable takes less resources than a non-nullable Int to initialize is false. A nullable variable has to point to null so either way you are assigning 32 bits of memory for the variable. But when you go to actually store something in it, the nullable Int will use a wrapper so it will be much bigger than 32 bits and use more CPU to wrap and unwrap it when you access it. All of this resource discussion is completely moot, though. The difference is infinitesimal unless you’ve got a big array of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that both options are valid and expected, even the `lateinit` which as you mentioned is not an option.

It's important on what you would like to do with the variable.

1. Do you want to treat the variable as nullable to detect if the intent's extra was read? If yes, then go with nullable.
2. Do you want to treat it as non nullable and have a single default value for when the argument is missing? If yes, then go with the second option.

In my opinion, this kind of options should be consistent across a code base, therefore the better approach is to pick one which will be followed across the whole project so you know and recognise the case immediately without having second thoughts on what that might be.  At the end of the day, it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `lazy`?

```
private val myAmazingVariable by lazy { intent.getIntExtra("INT_PLACEHOLDER", 0) }
```

In your example of passing in an Int this is a great solution as you can provide a default value. You do need to be careful with other types though as they can be nullable. It's an option if you can be certain that the Intent contains this extra though.